# Missing: Outlook 16.0 Object library (msoutl.olb)

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

I'm running an MS Access database with VBA code that has libraries for Microsoft Office 2010.  Currently, there are users that are upgrading their machine to Windows 10 running Access 2016.

When the database is opened on a new machine running Access 2016 the libraries for the Outlook changes to 16.0.

When I try to open the file in the old Access 2010 environment, I run into this error:

> Missing msoutl.olb.

Is there a way to make the database backwards compatible?

Comment: Maybe change code to use late binding. Review https://superuser.com/questions/615463/how-to-avoid-references-in-vba-early-binding-vs-late-binding

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the users share the same frontend hosted in a network folder.

If not done already, *split* the database to have a single shared backend database file. Then, to avoid your issue, distribute a separate copy of the frontend to each user's workstation.

On the workstation, let the user launch the frontend using a *shortcut* that runs a script to always keep the frontend current. This method is described in detail in my article:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html)